# Popup dissapears when mouse leaves element

Tags: html, css, popup, hover

im creating a bodymap where hovering over an organ will reveal a popup where you can click to learn more about the disease
ive managed to make the hover work but when i mouse over to the popup itself, it dissapears. im aware that because my image map is only over the brain area (the black outline) it dissapears bc im using onmouseover but ive tried other mouse options to no avail.

this is an image of the body map
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uaMri.png
i cant click on the pop up bc its no longer in the mapping area

This is my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test!</title>
<style>

body    {background-color: #b3daff;}
img     {display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;}

div#brainpopup { width:200px;
    height:150px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #ff9966;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thick;
  border-color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 0;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-1000px;
    margin-left:400px;
}

div#heartpopup { width:200px;
    height:150px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ff9966;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thick;
  border-color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 0;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:-800px;
    margin-left:450px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="example">
    <img src="bodymap.jpg" usemap="#body" >  
        
        <div id="brainpopup" style="display:none;" onclick="document.getElementById('brainpopup').style.display='none';">
            <ul>
                <h4>Brain History</h4>
                <li><a href="brain.html">Brain Cancer</a></li>
                <li><a href="brain.html">Dementia</a></li>
                <li><a href="brain.html">Epilepsy</a></li>
                <li><a href="brain.html">Stroke</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
        <div id="heartpopup" style="display:none;" onclick="document.getElementById('heartpopup').style.display='none';">
            <ul>
                <h4>Heart History</h4>
                <li><a href="heart.html">Arrhythmia</a></li>
                <li><a href="heart.html">Hypertrophic cardiomyopathy</a></li>
                <li><a href="heart.html">Mitral regurgitation</a></li>
                <li><a href="heart.html">Dilated cardiomyopathy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
    
    <map name="protect">
        <area shape="rect" coords="18,65,38,93" href="#" alt="title" title="title" onclick="document.getElementById('popup').style.display='block';">
    </map>

<map name="body">
    <area shape="poly" coords="332,130,391,146,431,183,429,218,409,235,422,253,405,263,376,237,323,239,288,218,283,181,298,145" alt="brain" href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('brainpopup').style.display='block'" onmouseleave="document.getElementById('brainpopup').style.display='none'">
    <area shape="poly" coords="382,536,394,548,404,571,430,587,434,610,432,646,417,661,390,651,363,635,351,611,353,598,344,559" alt="heart" href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('heartpopup').style.display='block'" onmouseover="document.getElementById('heartpopup').style.display='none'">
    <area shape="poly" coords="375,679,425,668,450,680,471,702,473,744,452,775,420,793,380,797,344,782,331,761,367,749,378,731,374,708" alt="stomach" href="stomach.html">
</map>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i don't understand you well, what you want and what's your problem?please describe more.the popup disappears because you change **display** to **none** with **onmouseleave** event

Comment: i want to be able to mouse over to the brain and click on the popup but the popup dissapears when i mouse over it because its outside the image map

Answer (score 0):

Take a look if that's what you want. Now the Picture apears onhover the "Brain History" box and won't go away tell you click on "Brain History" box.

```js
brainpopup.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
  example.querySelector("img").style.display = "block";
})
brainpopup.addEventListener("click",function(){
example.querySelector("img").style.display="none";
})
```

```css
img     {display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;}
#example img{
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  left:40%;
}

div#brainpopup { width:200px;
    height:150px;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #ff9966;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thick;
  border-color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

div#heartpopup { width:200px;
    height:150px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #ff9966;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: thick;
  border-color: #fff;
  padding: 8px 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
<title>Test!</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="example">
    <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Ftse4.explicit.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.pAGacHhjpQWnqz3kX2RtYwHaE8%26pid%3DApi&f=1" usemap="#body" >
  <div id="brainpopup"> 
    <ul>
      <h4>Brain History</h4>
      <li><a href="brain.html">Brain Cancer</a></li>
      <li><a href="brain.html">Epilepsy</a></li>
      <li><a href="brain.html">Stroke</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
  <div id="heartpopup">
    <ul>
      <h4>Heart History</h4>
      <li><a href="heart.html">Arrhythmia</a></li>
      <li><a href="heart.html">Hypertrophic cardiomyopathy</a></li>
      <li><a href="heart.html">Mitral regurgitation</a></li>
      <li><a href="heart.html">Dilated cardiomyopathy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>
    
    <map name="protect">
        <area shape="rect" coords="18,65,38,93" href="#" alt="title" title="title">
    </map>

<map name="body">
    <area shape="poly" coords="332,130,391,146,431,183,429,218,409,235,422,253,405,263,376,237,323,239,288,218,283,181,298,145" alt="brain" href="#">
    <area shape="poly" coords="382,536,394,548,404,571,430,587,434,610,432,646,417,661,390,651,363,635,351,611,353,598,344,559" alt="heart" href="#">
    <area shape="poly" coords="375,679,425,668,450,680,471,702,473,744,452,775,420,793,380,797,344,782,331,761,367,749,378,731,374,708" alt="stomach" href="stomach.html">
</map>

</body>
```

Comment: yes i left those as a placeholder when i was experimenting on methods. even upon removal it still does now allow me to click on the popup

Comment: does *not allow

Comment: Is it your Website online? or can you post your functional code some where? like: https://codepen.io to test it?

Comment: no its not. ive tested it but the same problem still persists

Comment: I mean if you can post your functional code some where, so I can test ;)

Comment: ohh sorry my bad! the code i posted in the question is my whole complete code